# How to open DownThemAll! in a tab?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

How to make the [DownThemAll!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) Firefox extension open in a new tab instead of a separate window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no native way to do it, but this add-on can make DownThemAll! and other Firefox extensions use tabs instead of new windows: [More In Content UI+](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/more-in-content-ui-plus/) .

Answer (score 5):

Type *chrome://dta/content/dta/manager.xul* in the address bar.

Comment: My question was about opening it in new tabs automatically (after clicking on the extension icon, for example).